# Constantly checking for shared memory to change while in a loop

Tags: c, sockets, loops, shared-memory

I have a loop that is always true to allow other clients to connect. The problem I am having is how do I constantly check the shared memory to see if it changes to know when it is time to shut down the server? The while loop I put in works but it will not let any other clients to connect after. The issue is that in the while(1) loop, it has to wait for another client to connect before going through the loop but I need it to always be checking the shared memory not just when another client connects.

```
    #include <sys/types.h>
    #include <netinet/in.h>
    #include <sys/socket.h>
    #include <errno.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <strings.h>
    #include <sys/ipc.h>
    #include <sys/shm.h>
    #include <sys/wait.h>

    struct sockaddr_in sn;
    struct sockaddr from;

    int main(int ac, char** other){
      int s, ns, sl, x = 22, pid;
      char b[256];
      key_t key=137; 
      int size=1;
      int shmflg=0;
      int id=0,ok=0;
      char shmstr[10];
      char istr[10];
      int *shmptr;

      size=size*sizeof(int);
      shmflg=IPC_CREAT | SHM_R | SHM_W;
      id=shmget(key,size,shmflg);
      sprintf(shmstr,"%d",id);
      shmptr=shmat(id,0,0);
      shmptr[0]=0;

      s=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM,0);
      if (s<0) {
        printf("server socket error\n");
         exit(0);}
      else {}

      bzero((char *)&sn, sizeof(sn));
      sn.sin_family = AF_INET;
      sn.sin_port = htons(3311);

      if (bind(s,(struct sockaddr *)&sn,sizeof(sn))==-1){
        printf("server bind error %d\n",errno);
        exit(0);}
      else {}

      listen(s,3);
   ////////////////////////////////////****************************************
      while (1){
        sl=sizeof(from);
        ns =accept(s,&from,&sl);
        if (ns <0) {
          printf("server accept error");
          exit(0);}
        else {}
        sprintf(b,"%d",ns);
        if ((pid=fork()) == 0) {
          sprintf(istr, "%d",ok);
          execlp(other[1], other[1], b, shmstr, istr, (char*) NULL);

        }
        else {
          while(shmptr[0]==0){}//allows the server to shut down but no more clients connect
            close(s);
            exit(0);
          }  
        }

       } 
    ////////////////////////////////////////////*************************
      close(s);
      return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Then check for all those conditions in your polling loop. Also use `memset` instead of `bzero` it's deprecated. Also if you're using sockets why use shared memory, why not just call accept in a loop and spawn threads to handle requests?

Comment: I tried that but it still would have to sit at ns=accept. I need it to be at any given time and any given client that sets shared memory to 0 for the server to shut down. It is part of a project, we have to use shared memory.

Comment: @Joe, How many threads are sharing the memory?  More than two?  Perhaps the code could implement a semaphore, or signal, that your thread could block (ie:wait) for?

Comment: Correct. As many as I would want to connect.

Comment: @Joe, perhaps you should consider implementing a semaphore (located in the shared memory).

Comment: Thank you for your trouble, but non-blocking socket is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, non-blocking socket is what you are looking for.

[edit:]
use `select`

http://www.scottklement.com/rpg/socktut/nonblocking.html

> Non-blocking sockets can also be used in conjunction with the select()
>   API. In fact, if you reach a point where you actually WANT to wait for
>   data on a socket that was previously marked as "non-blocking", you
>   could simulate a blocking recv() just by calling select() first,
>   followed by recv().